# Accepting tree nodes from keyboard for determining it's height

Tags: c++

I have a code that can determine tree height by hard coding it's values

I tried using container like structures but still was not successful, instead of posting what I have tried on the part of accepting tree nodes fro the Input which is actually messy,I decided to post the code with hard coded tree nodes, what I need is for the program to accept tree nodes from the keyboard with the following helper description for input

Input:

The first line is an integer N indicating the number of nodes.

For each of the next few lines, there are two integers  include a and b.b is a child of a.

example:

```
5 // number of nodes
1 2
1 3
3 4
3 5
```

in which the height will be 3

```
// C++ program to find height of tree 
#include <bits/stdc++.h> 
using namespace std; 


/* A binary tree node has data, pointer to left child 
and a pointer to right child */
class node 
{ 
    public: 
    int data; 
    node* left; 
    node* right; 
}; 

/* Compute the "maxDepth" of a tree -- the number of 
    nodes along the longest path from the root node 
    down to the farthest leaf node.*/
int maxDepth(node* node) 
{ 
    if (node == NULL) 
        return 0; 
    else
    { 
        /* compute the depth of each subtree */
        int lDepth = maxDepth(node->left); 
        int rDepth = maxDepth(node->right); 

        /* use the larger one */
        if (lDepth > rDepth) 
            return(lDepth + 1); 
        else return(rDepth + 1); 
    } 
} 

/* Helper function that allocates a new node with the 
given data and NULL left and right pointers. */
node* newNode(int data) 
{ 
    node* Node = new node(); 
    Node->data = data; 
    Node->left = NULL; 
    Node->right = NULL; 

    return(Node); 
} 

// Driver code   
int main() 
{ 
    node *root = newNode(1); 

    root->left = newNode(2); 
    root->right = newNode(3); 
    root->left->left = newNode(4); 
    root->left->right = newNode(5); 

    cout << "Height of tree is " << maxDepth(root); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: is it correct, that your actual problem is not related to trees but just about how to read input from the user? Do you know how to read an `int` via `std::cin` ?

Comment: Sounds like you need to make a function `node *find_node(int n)`. Then another function `void add_child(node *parent, int n)`.

Comment: yes the actual problem is not related to trees but just about how to read input from the user, yes I know how to how to read an int via std::cin , and but it appeared to me after so many trials that it is not that simple, if you could demonstrate, will much appreciate it.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp could you please demonstrate, I am not very knowledgeable on the use of pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the input identifies the parent node by its data value, we need a helper function to find it:

```
node *findNode(node *node, int data)
{
    if (!node) return 0;
    if (node->data == data) return node;
    class node *found;
    (found = findNode(node->left, data)) || (found = findNode(node->right, data));
    return found;
}
```

Then we can code the input processing, e. g.:

```
    node *node, *root = 0;  // initially empty
    int nn, a, b;
    cin>>nn;
    while (cin>>a>>b)
    {
        if (!root)
            root = newNode(a),
            node = root;
        else
            node = findNode(root, a);
        if (!node->left) node->left  = newNode(b);
        else             node->right = newNode(b);
    }
```